# Role based on Windows login on Analysis Services

Tags: ssas, roles

My company has 10 sales persons, and I want that each person can view in my sales cube, only the data linked to this person.

For example Anne MARTIN will only see her sales and not the sales of Patrick DUMONT.
I already created a role that work fine for Anne MARTIN, but if I have 10 sales persons, I have to duplicate this role 10 times and create a new one for each new employee.

Everybody use a Windows credential, for example "domain\amartin" and I want to use this credential in my role to link with my dimension "sales person" and authorize to see only data linked with amartin.

I found some code on the net but I did not obtain anything ...
Is it possible and how to do it ?

thanks.
Damien.

Comment: Is it Tabular or Multidimensional? What 'code' on the net did you find? You don't need code to do this, it's baked into the product. If it's tabular, start reading here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-tutorial-row-level-security-onprem-ssas-tabular

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I work on multidimensional mode. I did not write what I tried, but I thought that I found Something like "USERNAME" or "CURRENT_USER" in MDX. The procedure was to add it in the role and make the correspondance between the result of the MDX instruction and my data.

Comment: I just tried this :
WITH MEMBER Measures.x AS UserName  
SELECT Measures.x ON COLUMNS  
FROM [Cube Ventes] 
The result is "domain\login" maybe I can use this in my role and try Something with this. I will try soon.

Answer (score 0):

It is common practice to create roles and assign membership to separate operations. Often, the model designer adds roles during the design phase. This way, all role definitions are reflected in the project files that define the model. Role membership is typically rolled out later as the database moves into production, usually by database administrators who create scripts that can be developed, tested, and run as an independent operation.